# Combinatorics: Getting all of the chocolates in a square at minimum cost

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a $101$ by $101$ square array. Each unit square is surrounded by a fence. However, if two squares share a common edge, there is a doorway between the fence along their common edge. It costs $\$1$ each time a person wants to pass through a doorway.

In each of $5101$ of the unit squares, one chocolate is placed. Jake wants to collect all the chocolates. He is permitted to select any square in the array to begin his journey and may only change squares by passing through a doorway. What is the minimum amount of cash Jake should carry with him in order to be guaranteed, that if he is smart enough, he will collect all of the chocolates.

I've tried to do a worst possible case type argument, but it's hard to work out a worst possible case given the added complexity of Jake being able to choose his starting location.

Is the fact that $101$ prime, relevant? Could we try small primes with $\frac{p+1}{2}$ chocolates and do some sort of induction?

Comment: Shouldn't a $101$ by $101$ array have $10201$ squares? I'm not clear where the $5101$ comes in...

Comment: Perhaps you mean "In each of 5101 of the unit squares"? In that case, does Jake know where the chocolates are?

Comment: Yes @Ben Millwood, I mean that, sorry for the typo, and yes He does know where the chocolates are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Color the squares like a checkerboard.  If the corners are white, there are $5101$ white squares.  The worst case is that the chocolates are in all the white squares.  Jake will have to go through all the squares to get all the chocolate and will need $\$10200$ to do that.

This applies if every pass through a door costs.  If you can leave a door open and go back through it free, you can do better.  I think you can miss almost half the black squares then.

Comment: That is the worst case, it isn't a strategy if the chocolate positions are known.

Comment: @vonbrand:  I am assuming the positions are known, but we were asked for the worst case.  In this configuration, he has to go through a black square to get from each white to the next, so he still needs this much money.

Answer (score -2):

The greedy chocolate eater will have to go from one square to the next, so they can't do better than 5100 doors. Just starting on one corner and going down along the border, then the next line up, and so clearly doesn't do "too many" doors.

Comment: See the clarification in the comments. I think you have to come up with a strategy that works even if the chocolates are not adjacent.

Comment: Sorry, $101^2=10201$, there was a small mistake in the question that might have led you to believe otherwise. There are $10201$ unit squares, but only $5101$ of them have chocolate in them.

Comment: @BenMillwood, then it is too similar to the travelling salesman problem to have any sort of "easey solution", I'm afraid.

Comment: @vonbrand: Are you sure? It sounds like a major simplification to me.